# How can I fix the pixel error when the keyboard is opened?

Tags: flutter, dart

> Hello everyone, I am sharing the code of a login screen below. When I click on the textfields on this login screen, I encounter a pixel error when the keyboard opens. Images are also available below. I would be glad if you help.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class loginpage extends StatefulWidget {
  loginpage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<loginpage> createState() => _loginpageState();
}

class _loginpageState extends State<loginpage> {
  TextEditingController? textController1;
  TextEditingController? textController2;
  bool? passwordVisibility;
  final formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();
  final scaffoldKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    textController1 = TextEditingController();
    textController2 = TextEditingController();
    passwordVisibility = false;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      backgroundColor: Color(0xFF262D34),
      body: Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 1,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          color: Color(0xFF262D34),
        ),
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          children: [
            Align(
              alignment: AlignmentDirectional(0, 0),
              child: Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 100, 0, 0),
                child: Image.asset(
                  'assets/logo/logo.png',
                  width: 200,
                  height: 200,
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
            ),
            SingleChildScrollView(
              child: Container(
                width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                height: 370,
                decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                  color: Color.fromARGB(255, 255, 255, 255),
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                    bottomLeft: Radius.circular(0),
                    bottomRight: Radius.circular(0),
                    topLeft: Radius.circular(16),
                    topRight: Radius.circular(16),
                  ),
                ),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: [
                        Padding(
                          padding:
                              EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 12, 20, 0),
                          child: Row(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding:
                                    EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(20, 0, 0, 0),
                                child: Text(
                                  'Welcome back',
                                  style: TextStyle(
                                    fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                    fontSize: 18,
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                width: 40,
                                height: 40,
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                  shape: BoxShape.circle,
                                  border: Border.all(
                                    color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7),
                                  ),
                                ),
                                child: Icon(
                                  Icons.phone,
                                  color: Colors.black,
                                  size: 18,
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                        Form(
                          key: formKey,
                          autovalidateMode: AutovalidateMode.disabled,
                          child: Column(
                            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                            children: [
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                    20, 12, 20, 0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        controller: textController1,
                                        obscureText: false,
                                        decoration: const InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'Email Address',
                                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7),
                                              width: 2,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                              topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7),
                                              width: 2,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                const BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                              topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                    20, 12, 20, 0),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  children: [
                                    Expanded(
                                      child: TextFormField(
                                        controller: textController2,
                                        obscureText: passwordVisibility!,
                                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                                          labelText: 'Password',
                                          enabledBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7),
                                              width: 2,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                const BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                              topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                                            borderSide: BorderSide(
                                              color: Color(0xFFDBE2E7),
                                              width: 2,
                                            ),
                                            borderRadius:
                                                const BorderRadius.only(
                                              topLeft: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                              topRight: Radius.circular(4.0),
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                          suffixIcon: InkWell(
                                            onTap: () => setState(
                                              () => passwordVisibility =
                                                  passwordVisibility!,
                                            ),
                                            child: Icon(
                                              passwordVisibility!
                                                  ? Icons.visibility_outlined
                                                  : Icons
                                                      .visibility_off_outlined,
                                              color: Color(0xFF757575),
                                              size: 18,
                                            ),
                                          ),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                              Padding(
                                padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(
                                    20, 12, 20, 16),
                                child: Row(
                                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                                  mainAxisAlignment:
                                      MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                                  children: [
                                    Text(
                                      'Forgat Password?',
                                      style: TextStyle(
                                        fontFamily: 'Poppins',
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                    SizedBox(
                                      width: 130,
                                      height: 40,
                                      child: ElevatedButton(
                                        onPressed: () {
                                          print('Button pressed ...');
                                        },
                                        child: Text("LOGIN"),
                                        style: ButtonStyle(
                                          shape: MaterialStateProperty.all<
                                                  RoundedRectangleBorder>(
                                              RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                            borderRadius:
                                                BorderRadius.circular(12),
                                            side: BorderSide(
                                                color: Colors.transparent,
                                                width: 1),
                                          )),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ],
                                ),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      ],
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]
[image]

> As you can see above, when I click on the textfields, I encounter the problem as above.

Answer (score 0):

warp your Column with single child scroll view

this link will help you more
https://medium.com/zipper-studios/the-keyboard-causes-the-bottom-overflowed-error-5da150a1c660